# Windows Server 2008 Web Edition Configuration to make website see image file

Tags: java, windows, tomcat

I am trying to get a website up in tomcat, and while the sample sites have worked, this website is not seeing the images in the content/images folder. Is there some configuration file that needs to be modified for them to be referenced properly?

To see what I am talking about 208.73.99.218:8080/cott/ (using IE will display the page properly in my testing, I am all about the linux)

Answer (score 0):

have you checked to see if the path to your images is correct? one of your image links is: src="/cott/content/images/b_search.gif" make sure that the image is located relative to where the site is being run.

For example, if your site is being run in ~/FOO_SITE, make sure the images are located here:
~/FOO_SITE/cott/content/images/b_search.gif, if thats the right place.

Comment: This is where the WAR file expanded the files for that site. Tomcat 5.5\webapps\cott\content\images

Comment: when I get frustrated over image issues I'd just copy them into every level of the tree till they showed up and just take them out one by one.

Comment: Progress, now it is an issue of the source name not fully being served..example is the css file is located at http://localhost/cott/content/cott.css, but the page is trying to read content/cott.css, no idea why its not propagating properly..